# 3D SparseTensor matrix multiplication with 2D Tensor :InvalidArgumentError: Tensor 'a_shape' must have 2 elements [Op:SparseTensorDenseMatMul]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Hi I am tryigng to do a  3D SparseTensor matrix multiplication with 2D Tensor. Here is a toy example:

**3D tensor  matrix multiplication with 2D Tensor**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1., 0., 2., 0.],
              [3., 0., 0., 4.]]])
b = (np.array([1., 2.])[:,np.newaxis]).T

a_t = tf.constant(a)
b_t = tf.constant(b)
    
tf.matmul(b_t,a_t)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[[7., 0., 2., 8.]]])>
```

**3D SparseTensor  matrix multiplication with 2D Tensor**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1., 0., 2., 0.],
              [3., 0., 0., 4.]]])
b = (np.array([1., 2.])[:,np.newaxis]).T

a_t = tf.constant(a)
b_t = tf.constant(b)

a_s = tf.sparse.from_dense(a_t)

tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(b_t,a_s)

InvalidArgumentError: Tensor 'a_shape' must have 2 elements [Op:SparseTensorDenseMatMul]
```

Can you please help me to sort out this error?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/sparse_dense_matmul) says that the rank of the dense matrix must be 2.

> Multiply SparseTensor (or dense Matrix) (of rank 2) "A" by dense matrix

Te first argument of the call of this function is:

> SparseTensor (or dense Matrix) A, of rank 2.

So you can do what you're trying to do, at least not this way. Seems like you don't really need the three dimensions, as one of them is just one. If you squeeze it out, it will work:

```
a_t = tf.constant(tf.squeeze(a))
b_t = tf.constant(b)

a_s = tf.sparse.from_dense(a_t)

tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(b_t,a_s)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[7., 0., 2., 8.]])>
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this question. But unfortunately i cannot adopt this approach as i have more than one for the third demention. So this means tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul cannot handle 3 dimension tensors?

Comment: That seems to be the case. The only approach I see is having a for loop across the third dimension/third axis. Though that is not a vectorized approach and would be in-efficient.